# Calculate the rank of a type signature of Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I know the id has rank 1 and rank3 has rank 3. However, I am not sure whether there are some formula to calculate the ranks. For the order of a function we have:

```
order(c) = 0 
order(A -> B) = max(order(A)+1, order(B))

rank1   :: forall a. a -> a
rank2   :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (b -> b)
rank3   :: ((forall a. a -> a) -> (Bool, Char)) -> (Char, Bool)
```

It seems that the rank is dependent on the "depth" of "forall" in the type signature, but this is not clear enough for me to see it. I have the following questions:

1. What is the rank of `undefined :: forall a. a`? It is 0 or 1?
2. What is the rank of `f :: ((a -> a) -> (forall a. a -> a)) -> (forall b. b -> b)`?  2?
3. Is there a formula to calculate the number of rank explicitly?
4. If there is no formula, can someone just tell me how to count the rank explicitly?

Comment: See (e.g.) Section 3.1 in https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362474/1651941